# session is always empty outside of the file where is generated

Tags: php, session, webserver, server-configuration

Why I am getting an empty array of the session when I am trying a `var_dump` in another page?
In the server, the session is stored without any content, only with the name of the id.
With cookies all works well. Sometimes (yes, sometimes), I restart the server, and then, the sessions works well too. What may cause this issue?

Maybe a bug of the php 5.1.6? or a problem in the config of the server?

**index_2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['xxx'] = "tessstsse";
var_dump($_SESSION);//here show the correct session
header( 'Location: index_3.php');
```

**index_3.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

The output of this will be:

```
array
  empty
```

Comment: do `echo session_id();` in both scripts. if the ID changes, then you've got a cookie problem, and are getting a new/clean session each time.

Comment: @MarcB i have the same session_id in both files.

Comment: also check that there's no overly-enthusiastic cleanup script deleting session files, and/or session expiry settings in php ([session.gc_maxliftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) and company) killing things too quickly

Comment: maybe you should check if the session save path in /var/php_sessions is writable by the web server.

Comment: @MarcB this is the config of the sessions in my server: http://tny.cz/b841923f

Comment: @anvd: that all looks fine. is that from a phpinfo() call in the same dir as your problematic scripts? if it's from somewhere else, redo it in the same location. php overrides can be littered everywhere on a system and one file can have totally different settings than any other one.

Comment: @MarcB yes, I do the phpinfo() inside of index_2.php, and i also do a chmod -R 777 in the /var/lib/php/session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the web server without space to store the session content.

0% of free space. Delete some data and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.. if this works I'd re examine your code else it is probably an issue with your server...

page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = "true";
    $_SESSION['superhero'] = "batman";
?>
<a href="page2.php">Click here</a>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); // start the session before using it
    //echo $_SESSION['auth']; // will output 'true'
    print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

destroy.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); // start the session before using it
    session_destroy(); // deletes the current session..
?>
```

Comment: It should normally output an array containing auth and superhero. I would try putting session_destroy(); in a page - run it - then run my code from above and see if there is any change. I will add the session_destroy() to my code above.

Comment: I fail to see how destroying a session will do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm thinking that you have an issue with the current session. It would pay to delete the current one and create a fresh one. That way you will be able to narrow down where the issue lies. If you cannot create a new session then it may be that you do not have adaquate permissions for example. This won't fix your current session, but if there is an issue with the current session it will give you a clean slate as it were.